# robotis.launch How to define motor parameters?

Tags: ros, pi-tracker, robotis, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

While working with pi_tracker I have been trying to get some Bioloid Dynamixel ax-12a motors to move with kinect input. I have managed to get input to to move the motors and am now wondering where I can define motor/joint ID's for the robotis.launch parameters.

I am unsure as to whether I am supposed to edit the dynamixel parameters(pi_tracker/params/dynamixels_params.yaml) or add to the robotis parameters(pi_tracker/params/robotis_params.yaml). Or is there another way to define my motor setup so that the proper motor moves?

Thank you for your time.

Installed:

Ubuntu 12.04 x64

fuerte

pi_tracker

robotis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57692/robotis.launch-how-to-define-motor-parameters?/) by [Zab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4384/zab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2013-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Zab,

The robotis package uses another config file in the bin directory of the pi_tracker package called servo_config.py.  I believe that's the one you are looking for.

**UPDATE**: It turns out that there is also a servo_config.py file in the robotis package directory and that this file will override the one in the pi_tracker/bin directory.  So you need to ensure that both files contain the same parameters.  Two ways of doing this are as follows:

```
$ roscd robotis/src/robotis
$ roscp pi_tracker servo_config.py .
```

(That isolated "." at the end of the second line is required.)  This method requires that you execute the above commands whenever you change the parameters in the pi_tracker copy.

Alternatively you could just symlink the two files like this:

```
$ roscd robotis/src/robotis
$ rm servo_config.py servo_config.pyc
$ ln -s `rospack find pi_tracker`/bin/servo_config.py .
```

This method will keep the robotis copy synced with the pi_tracker version.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zab](https://answers.ros.org/users/4384/zab/) on 2013-03-11**:
Yes it is! Thanks again!